# Vue-table-2 select all rows option

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I have a table using vue-table2.js. I need to put an input checkbox to check all rows using the vue-table2.js.

Can I put it as an option?

I want to put as the arrow refers to.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NBey.jpg)

Here is my code

```
        Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            checkedRows:[],         
            allSelected: false,
            showModal: false,                
            columns: ['selected','nameAr', 'nameEn', 'edit', 'del'],
            data: getData(),
            options: {
                headings: {
                    nameAr: 'News English Title',
                    nameEn: 'News Arabic Title',
                    edit: 'Edit',
                    del: 'Delete'
                },
                filterByColumn: true,
                sortable: ['nameAr', 'nameEn'],
                filterable: ['nameAr', 'nameEn']
            }
        } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could change it without any need to do a thing.

```
 Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            checkedRows:[],         
            allSelected: false,
            showModal: false,                
            columns: ['selected','nameAr', 'nameEn', 'edit', 'del'],
            data: getData(),
            options: {
                headings: {
                    nameAr: 'News English Title',
                    nameEn: 'News Arabic Title',
                    edit: 'Edit',
                    del: 'Delete'
                },
                filterByColumn: true,
                sortable: ['nameAr', 'nameEn'],
                filterable: ['nameAr', 'nameEn']
            }
        } });
```